# Where is the JavaScript's execution stack used on the pc?

Tags: javascript, process, stack

I am currently watching a course about JavaScript and I learned something about the execution contexts and the execution stack. This topic did, however, release some questions in me:

I understand how the execution stack works and I know that every process has its own stack. But is this execution stack then the replacement for the normal process stack? Or can this execution stack be found on a different level?

The JavaScript code is executed by the engine of a browser if I am right. So, is the execution stack used in this engine or somewhere else? How and where does the execution of JS code take place on the computer? Because for example, a browser like FireFox is a process in itself.

So I assume that FireFox, of course, has its own stack, but what about the JavaScript code that is executed in it? Or is a new process created during the execution of JavaScript code on the machine?

I can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is an interpreted language and as such is ran by an interpreter which is called the JS engine. While most commonly a JS engine runs in web browsers, it's not limited or restricted to browsers, e.g. NodeJS runs it's own server side JS interpreter. A JS engine is an implementation of the ECMA Script standard, [see a list of engines on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine). Some implementations are open source and are built into completely different software, for instance Google Chrome and NodeJS both use the V8 engine to execute JS code.

> I know that every process has it's own stack. But is this execution
>   stack then the replacement for the normal process stack?

A browser runs its own OS process and most will use multiple OS processes (like Chrome [uses renderers](https://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html) each with a separate instance of the JS engine but related websites will share the same renderer thus JS engine) but the **important point is to NOT confuse an OS process execution context with a JS execution context**. The latter exists within the former.

An OS process runs the JS engine itself. The execution context of the OS process is controlled by the OS (kernel) while the execution context of JS is controlled by the JS engine.

Therefore, the idea of JS execution stack replacing normal process stack is of course nonsense.